# How to return saved MongoDB object in GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, graphql

Line 26 is executing before line 24 even though I am using await. I want to return the link object, but cannot. Null is always returned to GraphQL and I get the error "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.createLink."

I'm guessing it's a problem with async/promises and I'm not handling them correctly, but I thought await would sort it out. Surely if it's printing the Link object correctly then it's returning that same object? Because why would GraphQL get null if it's not printing null in the terminal?

Thanks.

[image: Type definitions]

[image: Code and terminal]

Comment: @xadm my type definition for Link already includes ID. When res is not null, it returns the object just fine. And when res is null, it creates and saves the object just fine, but it doesn't return the right object. I have to call the mutation again to get the object that was saved from the previous mutation.

Comment: `await Link.findOne` ?

Comment: @xadm Already tried, doesn't work. It still goes to line 29 before line 26 is done. Null is being returned and then the correct thing is being returned, but IDK why,